# Add month selected datapicker jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i want add 1 month from selected start date(inizio) because i need to send a form where fine(end) date have min date the date of the being date selected, sorry for the english,anyone help ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="piano_formativo.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script >
  function dataodierna(){
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    today= yyyy+'/'+mm+'/'+dd;
    return today;
    }
  $(function() {
        $( "#inizio" ).datepicker({
          minDate: new Date(dataodierna()),
          dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                $('#fine').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
          }
        });
        $( "#fine" ).datepicker({
          minDate: '+1m',
          dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,

        });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to set the **min date** of the "fine" date input to date selected in the "inizio" input plus 1 month?
Then you can simply do:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#inizio" ).datepicker({
      minDate: new Date(),
      dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var plusMonthDate = new Date(selectedDate);
        plusMonthDate.setMonth(plusMonthDate.getMonth()+1)
        $('#fine').datepicker('option', 'minDate', plusMonthDate);
      }
    });
    $( "#fine" ).datepicker({
      minDate: '+1m',
      dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
    });
});
```

Also you dont need to do `minDate: new Date(dataodierna())` as `new Date()` itself already returns today's date.

If you want to set the date of "fine" to **exactly** one month after the date selected in "inizio", you can do this:

```
$(function() {
   $( "#inizio" ).datepicker({
      minDate: new Date(),
      dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var plusMonthDate = new Date(selectedDate);
        plusMonthDate.setMonth(plusMonthDate.getMonth()+1)
        $('#fine').datepicker('option', 'minDate', plusMonthDate);
        $('#fine').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', plusMonthDate);
        $('#fine').datepicker('setDate', plusMonthDate);
      }
    });
    $( "#fine" ).datepicker({
      minDate: '+1m',
      dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes i want to set the date of "fine" to exactly one month after the date selected in "inizio".  try your code and it works thanks